# When a constrained optimization problem and its Lagrangian are equivalent?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Assume both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are non-negative and non-convex scalar functions.
Further assume that for any $x_1,\, x_2$ it holds $f(x_1) \le f(x_2)$ if and only if $g(x_1) \ge g(x_2)$.

Can we say that for any $\alpha \ge 0$ in which $\{x: g(x)\le \alpha \}$ is not empty, there exist a $0\le\lambda\le 1$
such that
\begin{equation}
\min_x f(x) \ \ \ \mathrm{s.t.} \ \ g(x)\le \alpha
\end{equation}

and 
\begin{equation}
\min_x \big\{(1-\lambda) f(x) + \lambda g(x)\big\}
\end{equation}

have same solution?

Comment: Nothing garantees that $g(x) \leq \alpha$ when solving the second problem.

Comment: @Bertrand, please look at the edited question.

Comment: Not many functions satisfy those requirements. I am removing the convex optimization tag and the numerical optimization tag because your problem does not involve convexity or numbers.